# ParserError reading Excel file with Python/Pandas read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm using pandas read_excel to read an Excel workbook into a dictionary of dataframes.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)

df_dict = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=none, 
   skiprows=list_of_rows_to_skip, 
   header=None, 
   usecols=list_of_cols_to_include, 
   names=list_of_col_names)
```

The first sheet of the Excel file is an info sheet, while the others (varies from one up to 60) has data in the same format. I specify `usercols` to include only colunms of interest.
However, all of a sudden I've started to get an error,

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Defining usecols without of bounds indices is not allowed. [1, 2, ... n]
```

To get around this problem I decided to read only the first sheet as a first step,

```
df_info = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name='info')
```

and then read the rest of the sheets. How could I do that? Since the function accepts a list, I tried slicing, `pd.read_excel(sheet_name=[1:], ...)`, which gave me an error, `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do : `df_info = df_dict.pop(list(df_dict)[0])`
The pop function will remove the first dictionnary from `df_dict` and store info in one dataframe.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, the ParseError occures at the df_dict = pd.read_excel(...) statement, so there's no df_dict to pop anything from.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the issue with loading multiple sheets, this function could help with that. You can then add the modifications you have already used with columns etc.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_excel_sheets(filename):
    df_dict = {} # placeholder to add other dataframes to
    xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    xl_sheets = xl_file.sheet_names # get the names of the sheets
    for sheet in xl_sheets:
        df_dict[sheet] = pd.read_excel(xl_file, sheet) # add each sheet as separate and named element in dictionary

    return df_dict

resulting_dict = get_excel_sheets(completePath2File)
```